# Azure Event Hub AMQP1.0 Sender with SAStoken

Tags: node.js, authentication, amqp, iot, azure-eventhub

I am currently trying to send information to Azure Event Hub with [AMQP1.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp10) client for node.js.
I need to authenticate through SAStoken.

I cannot use SASkey and SASKeyName that would look like this:

```js
var uri = protocol + '://' + encodeURIComponent(sasName) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(sasKey) + '@' + serviceBusHost;
```

Does anyone know how can I configure amqp10 or any other library to authenticate through SAStoken?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested, there is a Node.js library for Event Hubs. https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-node

That library makes a call to a referenced IoT library:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-node/blob/master/send_receive/lib/config.js#L18

Which is shown here:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/common/core/lib/shared_access_signature.js#L42